# lua socket handling multiple connections

Tags: lua, luasocket

my question is about lua sockets, say I have a chat and I want to make a bot for that chat. But the chat has multiple rooms all on defferent servers that are calculated by a function called `getServer` 
the connect function would look like this

```
function connect(room)
   con = socket.tcp()
   con:connect(getServer(room), port)
   con:settimeout(0)
   con:setoption('keepalive', true)
   con:send('auth' .. room)
```

and the function to loop it would be

```
function main()
   while true do
     rect, r, st = socket.select({con}, nil, 0.2)
     if (rect[con] ~= nil) then
        resp, err, part = con:receive("*l")
        if not( resp == nil) then
            self.events(resp)
 end
    end
       end
          end
```

now when all that runs it only receives data from the first room and I dunno how to fix that

Comment: Show the code where you call connect() for each rooms, and the main, don't show pieces. And fix the bad indentation.

Comment: I'll link it to a github repo because the file is to big ;( [link Github](https://github.com/ericraio/ch.lua/blob/master/ch.lua)[link] just add the socket.select() and thats pretty much what i got

Comment: This is not what I meant. Show the code that calls `connect(room)` and the code that calls `main()`. The link you attached contains neither of those.

Comment: I'm sorry, the `main()` function is the `ch_handler` function and the connect is called inside `ch_init` and the `ch_init` function is called in example.lua here [link example.lua](https://github.com/ericraio/ch.lua/blob/master/example.lua)

Comment: You need to create a [SSSCE](http://www.sscce.org/). Too much code. Perhaps the con, which is a global set in ch_connect and then used in ch_handler, but every connection will overwrite the reference with latest connection?

Comment: then if it overwrites how do I fix it, if this was python i'd just point the connection to a dict of the room name and then make a getCons function that returns the key and value lists then i would create a readers and writers list pass that onto the select then iterate through the read list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an array of connections. A map of room to connections might also be useful. Example:

```
local connections = {}
local roomConnMap = {}

function connect(room)
   local con = socket.tcp()
   con:connect(getServer(room), port)
   con:settimeout(0)
   con:setoption('keepalive', true)
   con:send('auth' .. room)

   table.insert(connections, con)
   roomConnMap[room] = con
end

function main()
   while true do
     local rect, r, st = socket.select(connections, nil, 0.2)
     for i, con in ipairs(rect) do 
        resp, err, part = con:receive("*l")
        if resp ~= nil then
            self.events(resp)
        end
     end
   end
end
```

Note that `rect` is an array of items found connections for which there is data to be read. So in the `for i,con` loop the con is the connection object, do not use `connections[con]` (this doesn't make sense because connections is an array, not a map).

Comment: I've tried this, first it says attempt to call a table value so I did `for con in ipairs(rect) do` and it never actually connects to the room

Comment: not exactly when I run with your code it connects to the room but doesn't receive data then I did, `for con in ipairs(rect) do resp, err, part = connection[con]:receive('*l')` because from what I understand. `socket.select()` Uses an array and that array holds every connection, selects job is to wait to receive data then outputs that connection as a number so for example connection holds two connections r1, r2. When r1 is receiving data the con value is 1 and when r2 receives data the con value is 2 right? But when it does get data it outputs an error.

Comment: that says, `attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)` and that error is coming from the `receive()`

Comment: @user3103366 That's because I had a couple bugs in the code I put. See if this is better. The code in your comment is missing a `i` which I put in my updated answer, and explain why not to use `connection[con]`. Note I used `connections` not `connection` since it is an array. Hope it works now.

Comment: thanks so much, it works now. The funny thing is I tried the for loop that way once before but I forgot to use ipairs instead of pairs this issue is resolved

Comment: Awesome' good to know. Don't forget to upvote any answers you find useful (for all questions you read, not just your own questions).